# Why is this program, which should sum each column, stopping after only one column?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

This program creates a table of numbers, and then attempts to sum it up, row by row. I'm using `IsBlank()` to test if the topmost cell is blank. If it is blank, it should end the loop, but if it isn't, the loop should keep going. However, it keeps ending after the first time through the loop. Why is that?

I have a feeling it's really obvious.

Edit: I should note that the whole "counter" thing is in there because I was going to start playing around with that if this worked. And it didn't work, so I'm here!

```
Option Explicit
Dim Counter As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim col As Long
Dim row As Long

Sub SumRange()
    For col = 1 To 8
        For row = 1 To 6
            Cells(row, col) = Rnd
        Next row
    Next col
    Counter = 6
    For i = 1 To 9
        If IsEmpty(Cells(1, i)) = False Then
            Cells(Counter + 1, i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(Counter, i)))
        Else
            End If
        End
    Next
    MsgBox Cells(4, 5)
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't you mean `Exit For` and not `End If`, or am I missing something?

Comment: And I think `If Not IsEmpty(Cells(1, i))` feels better than `If IsEmpty(Cells(1, i)) = False`

Comment: Oh yeah, I guess I do. When I changed that to `Exit For` to see if that fixed it, I got an error. "Compile Error: Next without For". And it highlighted the last Next in the program.

Comment: Yeah and I think you mean `End If` and not just `End`... `End` means to terminate the program if I remember right.

Comment: This was just a few dumb mistakes I didn't catch. We're all good now. If you put that as an answer, i'll check you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. The `End` statement is incorrect. If I remember correctly, `End` means to end the *program*. You have to explicitly state what you are ending (`End If`, `End With`, ...). In this case you mean `End If`.
2. You need to use `Exit For` to jump out of the for loop. I think you mean it to be where your current `End If` statement is.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but you can also consider using a while loop with the condition `While Not IsEmpty(Cells(1, i))` and then increment the counter `i` from within the loop. To me this feels a little better than a for loop with a jump in it.

Answer (score 4):

Remove `Else` and `End` from your code (the lines that only contain those statements) and your loop executes nine times.

The `End` Statement instructs VBA to ... end your code. So it simply exits.

I strongly recommend refactoring your code, it can be made much more efficient:

```
Sub SumRange()

  Dim values(1 To 6, 1 To 8) As Double
  Dim i As Long, j As Long

  ' populate array
  For i = LBound(values) To UBound(values)
    For j = LBound(values, 2) To UBound(values, 2)
      values(i, j) = Rnd
    Next j
  Next i

  ' blast array onto worksheet in one go
  Range("A1").Resize(UBound(values), UBound(values, 2)).value = values

  ' add sum formulas in one go
  Range("A1").Resize(, UBound(values, 2)).Offset(UBound(values)).FormulaR1C1 = _
  "=SUM(R[-" & UBound(values) & "]C[0]:R[-1]C[0])"

  MsgBox Cells(4, 5)
End Sub
```